# Deny access to all jpg urls that have a certain name in the url

Tags: .htaccess

I have jpg urls like these:

```
http://domain.com/members/content/upload/temp/1600watermarked/photo.jpg
http://domain.com/members/content/upload/test-123/1200watermarked/photo.jpg
http://domain.com/members/content/upload/random/1800watermarked/photo.jpg
```

In the folder content I have an htaccess file with this in there:

```
<FilesMatch /watermarked/.*>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

But that doesn't seem to work in blocking any jpg urls with the word "watermarked" in them. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well after some more experimenting I got this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)watermarked(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/forbidden.htm [R=301,L]
```

It's not exactly a forbidden error but it works better in my case since I can redirect them to a page to upgrade their accounts to see the blocked content.